# How to compare Boolean values using jQuery map()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing a jQuery selector as an argument and a year value into a function to test the value against a array of all the values from my select (the jQuery selector argument). I need it to return a Boolean true if any of the options values are the same as the "value" argument, but it always returns undefined.

```
 function checkOptions(selector, prop) {      
            var options = selector.children('option');
            var selectorValues = $.map(options, function(option) {
               if( option.value == prop ){
                    return !!(option.value == prop);
               }     
            });
        }
```

After changing my original code to reflect the suggestions made, the function still returns "undefined".

```
function checkOptions(selector, prop) { 
        var result;
        var options = selector.children('option');
        var selectorValues = $.map(options, function(option) {
                return option.value == prop;
        });
    }
```

The variable "selectorValues" holds these values at run-time:

```
selectorValues = [false, false, true, false, false]
```

This makes sense, because I am passing a "year" to prop that is one of the values of the options of the select.

Comment: Well, presumably that `if` condition never passes, so you never get to the `return`, hence why you only get `undefined`. If you want to just return all the booleans you can remove the `if`. You can also remove the `!!` as the check already returns a boolean

Comment: @vlaz, shouldn't map return an empty array if all returns are undefined?

Comment: @valarauko no, why would you think that? The `.map` functionality provides, perhaps unsurprisingly, a _mapping_ of one value to another. So, an array containing N values will generate a new array containing N values that obey the mapping. Or in other words if you start with `[1, 2, 3]` and your mapping is `x*2` that will be executed against each value and the new array would be `[2, 4, 6]`. You simply cannot make an empty array using this it's always 1:1. You are probably thinking of `.filter` which takes a predicate and returns anything that passes it.

Comment: Wait, did you want `checkOptions` to return a value? If so, it currently has no `return` statement, so it won't return anything - again, that results in `undefined`.

Comment: @vlaz That's on the array map function as is implemented on native javascript, but according to the jQuery.map documentation you can return null or undefined to remove the item (I'm not sure why they implemented it that way) Here is the link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: @valarauko I've not used the jQuery data iteration functions much, so I wasn't aware of that. And I do think that is indeed strange implementation, as it's different to how `.map` works in general, as the native implementation in JS follows the general cross-language functionality. I suspect jQuery is essentially doing the equivalent of what would normally be `array.map(func).filter(x => x)` just as a shorthand to avoid you typing the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function is not properly used in this situation which is why you got in trouble. It's role is to apply a transformation for each element of the array. Check out the [some function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). It is a predefined javascript function which does exactly what you want.

I would take the "array" of jquery objects, turn them into a native javascript array and call the some method on the them checking the desired condition.

```
function checkOptions(selector, prop) {
  var options = selector.find('option').toArray();
  var result = options.some(function(currentValue) {
    return (currentValue.text == prop); //using type coercion
  });
  return result;
}
```